# How to mount external ZFS file system without clobbering/altering current or external filesystem

Tags: mount, zfs

I am using FreeBSD 10.2 using ZFS on root as the file system *(zroot01)*.  I have an external hard disk with a ZFS file system from another FreeBSD 10.2 system *(zroot02)* that I want to temporarily mount, read only, so I can get some files off of it, then disconnect it afterward.  I *don't* want the external ZFS system to clobber or replace my current file system, nor do I want the data on the external to be corrupted/altered either.

To demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish, if I was using UFS I'd do something like this:

```
mount -t ufs -o ro /dev/ada0s2 /mnt/my-fun-mountpoint
```

...where `/dev/ada0s2` is the partition on my external drive and `/mnt/my-fun-mountpoint` is in the `/mnt` directory of my existing operating system.

All of the searching and man page reading has not provided a crystal-clear method for doing so.  What answers I *did* find ended up taking over my current file system and corrupting it beyond repair -- obviously not the result I'm looking for.  I attempted this a while ago so I don't remember which commands I tried, unfortunately.

Can you please provide some clear guidance on how to do this?  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, it really depends on *how* read-only you want the pool to be. And no, that's not a joke.

First, a bit of terminology: in ZFS, you *import* a pool, and optionally *mount* the (any) file systems within it. You can import a pool without mounting any file systems by passing `-N` to `zpool import` and then later on mount any desired file systems using `zfs mount`. (This is a perfectly valid scenario if, for example, you want to access only a single file system out of many, or if you want to do something resembling an off-line scrub of the pool.)

ZFS isn't a big fan of truly read-only access. For example, if ZFS detects an error that it is able to repair, I believe it will repair the error and write the repaired data to disk *even if you imported the pool as read-only.* My understanding is that, in ZFS parlace, "read-only" applies only to the *user-visible state* of the pool and its datasets. If, on the other hand, you make a binary copy of the disk to a file (or set of files), make those files truly read only, and try to import the pool from there, ZFS won't be able to import the pool at all no matter how hard you try. If you make the files writable, it will work fine. (I actually tried this just a few weeks ago, albeit using a zvol, and ZFS vehemently *refused* to import the pool. When I set the zvol to read/write instead of read-only, the pool imported fine.) Other file systems like (on Linux) ext4 and probably others handle this situation somewhat gracefully, but ZFS balks.

If you are unlucky, and [don't have ECC RAM](https://serverfault.com/q/454736/58408) installed in the system where you are importing the pool, then ZFS' attempting to correct any errors it encounters might actually [make things worse](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/ecc-vs-non-ecc-ram-and-zfs.15449/), although [opinions differ](http://jrs-s.net/2015/02/03/will-zfs-and-non-ecc-ram-kill-your-data/) on whether this is actually a real risk in practice. Personally I am of the opinion that any data I care enough about to protect with ZFS and snapshots and storage-level redundancy and [backups](https://serverfault.com/q/2888/58408) and whatnot [deserves](https://serverfault.com/a/673167/58408) the protection offered by ECC RAM also, but many PCs don't have ECC RAM.

So, you can import the pool in read-only mode, with a specific alternate root to keep it from stepping on anything else's toes, but you need to be aware that it isn't necessarily *truly* read-only in a forensic sense. (It will, however, ensure that you don't accidentally change anything in the pool.) To do a read-only import, assuming that the pool is named `tank` and that the device node(s) is/are available in `/dev`, you would use a command like:

```
# zpool import tank -d /dev -o readonly=on -R /mnt/someplace
```

This will look in `/dev` for anything holding a ZFS pool with the name `tank`, import it, temporarily setting the pool property `readonly` to `on` (which means that all user-initiated writes will be rejected) and temporarily setting its `altroot` property to `/mnt/someplace`. (These property values are "temporary" in the sense that they are not persisted to the disk(s) as current property values, so if you export and re-import the pool without them, the values will be back to normal. They might possibly be written to the pool history though, which once the pool is imported you can look at with `zpool history tank` if you are so inclined.) Once the pool is imported, you will see your files under /mnt/someplace and have normal, read-only access to them, including any snapshots that are already made on the datasets in the pool.

Given your example, I suspect that you would use something along the lines of:

```
# zpool import zroot02 -d /dev -o readonly=on -R /mnt/my-fun-mountpoint
```

When you are done, remember to cleanly export the pool:

```
# zpool export tank
```

or perhaps

```
# zpool export zroot02
```

That will unmount all file systems and other datasets within the pool, flush all buffers (to the extent that any need flushing in the first place), mark the pool as *not imported* on all constituent devices, and perform any other necessary housekeeping tasks to ensure that the pool can safely be moved to a different system and imported there later.

Comment: If you are really sure what you state in your third paragraph is correct, that would be a bug with the BSD ZFS implementation. ZFS pool read only import was designed to be truly read-only, i.e. it never tries to write or fix any data or metadata, including the pool history. See http://arc.stillopensolaris.org/txt/PSARC_2010_306.txt

Comment: @jlliagre I'm *quite* sure, but it *might* have been in the context of some other ZFS implementation. I don't really see why they would differ in such a fundamental aspect, though; I believe all open-source ZFS implementations share a significant amount of code that traces its lineage back to Sun. I just might set up some kind of testing environment for this and poke at it with a stick then see what happens, but it will be some time before I can devote the time to actually do that.

Comment: The fact that I apparently have "import" to simple *read a file* in ZFS is what troubles me.  I have a ZFS drive I am trying to access files from while the system it was originally in is unavailable.  When that system is available again, I want to put the drive back in it and resume as if nothing had happened.  But in the mean time I do need to access some of the files on the drive.  Hopefully your answer provides the information I need for this particular use case.